# Facebook messenger on wordpress website not working properly

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook-messenger

I'm trying to implement Facebook chat/messenger on my website. When I inject the code via functions.php it works in a weird way - on all pages/languages except default language (polish) homepage. This is the code:

```
// Messenger Chat
if ( ! function_exists('messenger_chat') ) {
  function messenger_chat() {
      echo '<div class="fb-customerchat"
      page_id="XXXXXX"
      logged_in_greeting="Witaj na stronie gabinetu. Jak możemy Ci pomóc?"
      logged_out_greeting="Witaj na stronie gabinetu. Jak możemy Ci pomóc?">
    </div>';
  }
}

// FB SDK
if ( ! function_exists('fb_sdk') ) {
  function fb_sdk() {
      echo '<script>window.fbAsyncInit=function(){FB.init({appId : "1678638095724206", autoLogAppEvents : true, xfbml : true, version : "v3.3"});}; (function(d, s, id){var js, fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)){return;}js=d.createElement(s); js.id=id; js.src="https://connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, "script", "facebook-jssdk"));</script>';
  }
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'messenger_chat');
add_action('wp_footer', 'fb_sdk');
```

The website has 3 languages: PL, EN, UA. On english and ukrainian it works smoothly. On polish subpages except homepage, as well. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check the code actually landed in the created output? Did you check if there were any messages related to this in the browser console? Are you outputting the same text as shown above for all three languages, or is it different ones? (And if the latter, do the other versions also have “special chars” inside the message texts?)

Comment: @04FS - finally after many hours got an explanation. I was using a caching plugin what was somehow related to the issue. plugin uses cloudflare, and without purging cloudflare cache, the issue was appearing. after cleaning, everything works smoothly!